# C- Need to simulate stdin within the code when calling a function

Tags: c, stdin

```
while( (reader=fread(array, sizeof(char), size, stdin))>0 )
```

I have this kind of guard what I need is within this cycle when I call a function I want to simulate that I'm giving my `fread` something.

Sorry about the scary English.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1 by the C standard. If you want to keep the code flexible, you could write `sizeof array[0]`, which will change appropriately if you change the type of the array. Otherwise, I'd just use 1. (But it's personal preference.)

Comment: Change `fread` to `my_fread` and write `my_fread` to do whatever you want.

Answer (score 4):

@Fritschy's answer with @Ben Voigt's comment constitute the portable solution.

If you're on Unix/Linux/similar, you can actually write things into `stdin` by

```
int p[2];

// error return checks omitted
pipe(p);
dup2(p[0], STDIN_FILENO);

FILE *stdin_writer = fdopen(p[1], "w");
```

Now write into `stdin_writer`.

See [`pipe`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html), [`dup2`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html), [`fdopen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fdopen.html) in the POSIX standard.

Answer (score 3):

You can replace stdin with a FILE* of your choice for testing:

```
FILE *test = fopen("mytestFile.txt", "r");
/* your code here... */
```

Or when need of stdin:

```
FILE *test = stdin;
/* your code here... */
```

Comment: how can i make this work with my guard in execution time, lets say i call i SIGINT and i want to pop out of my while but im waiting for the stdin input...

Comment: You could open files O_NONBLOCK or use select(2) or poll(2). Those however work only on plain FDs. You can get the FD from a FILE* with the fileno(3) function. See the manpages for more ;)

Comment: or, you could even call `freopen` on `stdin`.  Not recommended for production code, though in a unit test it could be useful.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is constructed on @Ben Voigt's comment.
Create `input.txt` with some text and `main.c` with this code.
The code will inject `input.txt` text into stdin and then send it into stdout.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);

    unsigned int BLOCK_SIZE = 3;
    char buffer[BLOCK_SIZE];

    for (;;) {
        size_t bytes = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), BLOCK_SIZE, stdin);
        fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), bytes, stdout);
        fflush(stdout);
        if (bytes < BLOCK_SIZE)
            if (feof(stdin))
                break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```